# Python long-polling pattern with requests

Tags: php, python, python-requests, long-polling

I'm doing the long-polling pattern with a PHP script and a MySQL database on a server and python script on the client.
If the flag in the database is set to 0, the PHP page responds with the id of the tupel. If the request times out, a new request should be started. This is my code and I can't find my mistake:

```
gotID = False
ID = 0

while gotID == False:
    f = requests.get("http://example.de/ajax_backend.php")
    print("status: " + str(f.status_code))
    print("content: " + f.text)
    if int(f.status_code) == 200:
        gotID = True
        ID = f.text
```

If I run the code like this i get this output. First the flag was set to 1, then in the middle i changed the flag to 0:

[image: console output python script]

I think there is an error in the `if` statement, but I can't find it. Can you help me?

Comment: please post the original responses from  http://example.de/ajax_backend.php for both cases (set and unset flags)

Comment: What is the problem? Is it that it exits the loop even if `f.status_code` returns 500?

Comment: The problem is, that the program stays in the while loop, no matter if the flag is set to 1 or 0. The program should leave the while loop if the flag is set to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now created a working code:

```
gotID = None
ID = 0

while not gotID:
    f = requests.get("http://example.de/ajax_backend.php")
    print("status: " + str(f.status_code))
    print("content: " + f.text)

    try:
        ID = int(f.text)
        gotID = "samlpe content"
    except ValueError:
        gotID = None
```

But i still don't know why my code above don't works.